# React component Styling using CSS

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have different CSS for Different React components.Currently am Using `import "./css/name.css"` to import local CSS but this same CSS is also being applied on another component even when i don't import this CSS for other Component.

Comment: can you post folder structure of app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use seperate css for every component you can [create react app module.css](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) feature

Answer (score 0):

css module will help, or alternatively you can install styled-component via npm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Okay , I didn't knew about the styled-component I'll use that . But I still have a query that is if I import a css for a component is it applicable to that component only to which it is imported or to every components

Comment: css module and styled-components will use scoped style. it mean **only** that imported component will use it. because styled-component/css module will randomly rename class to browser.